# is there a way to have cmake only build new rpm's for components where the binary has changed?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a large project managed by cmake which uses cpack to generate several rpms. When I run 'make package'  and every rpm is built every time, but my QE guys don't like this because they don't see an easy way to determine what is the minimal set of rpm's they need to deploy to get my changes.

so for example, if I have component  a, b and c. A clean build doing 'make package' should build a, b and c, but if I make a subsequent call to 'make package' where I only change the source of a binary in component c should result in only the rpm for component c being built.

Comment: So far, I have added this to main CMakeLists.txt:

foreach (COMPONENT ${CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL})
  add_custom_target(${COMPONENT}_package COMMAND  cpack -C Release -D CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL=${COMPONENT})
endforeach(COMPONENT)

this gives me a ${COMPONENT}_package target for each component. Now I need to figure out how to make it only run this target then the binaries are newer than the rpm

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but instead of relying on the build-time to determine which rpms are new, could you use version numbers instead?  If you use a versioning system like SVN, you could embed the working-copy revision in the package and use that to figure out which rpms are new.